# MySQL Select all rows not like the query

Tags: mysql

I tried searching both Stackoverflow and Google for this but didn't find anything, apoligizes if this is a duplicate and would appreciate if someone pointed me to the original question if one exists.

At the moment I have a table with 3 columns: id, starttime and endtime. I then use a query for a reservation that starts at 10:30 10.10.2014 and ends at 13:45 10.10.2014 like following:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM reservations 
 WHERE ('2014-10-10 10:30:00' BETWEEN starttime AND endtime)
         OR 
       ('2014-10-10 13:45:00' BETWEEN starttime AND endtime)
         OR 
       ('2014-10-10 10:30:00' >= starttime AND '2014-10-10 13:45:00' <= endtime)
         OR 
       ('2014-10-10 10:30:00' <= starttime AND '2014-10-10 13:45:00' >= endtime);
```

So the query checks if that reservation conflicts with any existing reservations and then returns the conflicting reservation. But I would like it to do the opposite and return all rows that dont conflict with the query.

I've been trying to solve this for many hours now and would appreciate any tips that push me to the right direction.

Comment: you can try NOT between? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-between

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified your query (shows conflicts):

```
SELECT *
 FROM reservations
 WHERE '2014-10-10 10:30:00' <= endtime
   AND starttime <= '2014-10-10 13:45:00'
```

To get all rows that don't conflict with the query dates:

```
SELECT *
 FROM reservations
 WHERE NOT ('2014-10-10 10:30:00' <= endtime
   AND starttime <= '2014-10-10 13:45:00')
```

Comment: Thanks you so much, you actually solved my problem thoroughly!

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
 select *
 from reservations
 where starttime >= '2014-10-10 10:40:00'
       and endtime <= '2014-10-10 13:45:00'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But this one seems to return the conflicting reservation. The answer by Rimas did what I was after.